# I want to delete or add the list element when I am browsing it

Tags: python, list

I want to delete or add the list element when I am browsing it but IndexError: list index out of range

```
listStep = ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '3', '1', '3', '0']

for i in range(0, len(listStep) - 2, 2):
    for j in range(i + 2, len(listStep), 2):
        if listStep[i + 1] == listStep[j + 1]:
            listStep[i] = listStep[i] + listStep[j]
            listStep.pop(j)
            listStep.pop(j)

print(listStep)
```

Desired output:

```
['03', '0', '013', '1']
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: It is unclear what the problem you are having is. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: output:  listStep = ['03', '0', '013', '1']

Answer (score 0):

All advice is not to mutate a list you are iterating through because it is difficult to reason about what happens when you do. Loop through a copy of the list instead using `[:]`.

Comment: Is there any way, I tried copying the new array but it is not like the desired output

Comment: Could you explain how to arrive at the output you are expecting from the input?  It really is not obvious from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Typical [off by one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), because array indices start at 0 and end at `length - 1`. I.e. `listStep[i + 1]]` for `i == len(listStep) - 1` (the last value of `range()`) is `len(listStep)`, i.e. you are accessing one element behind the end of the list.

You are also modifying the list as you process it so `len(listStep)` changes its value.

Comment: Is there any way, I tried copying the new array but it is not like the desired output

Comment: You would need to explain how the output result is calculated. I tried to understand that from your code, but couldn't explain the desired output result.